# Java swing applets change frame icon

Tags: java, swing, icons

How do I change the icon of a frame when loading the applet from JNLP?

I'm also using substance to change the appearance of the applet, and in a stand alone application the title changes with the skin I choose, but if I run the applet from webstart it always puts the default title bar (windows look). How can I change that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Untrusted code cannot change the icon.

Arguably that's a bit pointless now as you can draw the frame yourself on a frameless window. Although you probably don't have all the information necessary to get the frame exactly right on some systems, such as under Windows Aero with either blurry background or "watermarked" opaque pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean with "Untrusted code". It is my own applet. How can my code be untrusted?

Comment: Trusted code is code that has been granted more than usual permissions. For instance, the Java library is trusted. Untrusted code, such as applet downloaded from the internet, have only limited permissions (network with the "same-origin" server, and a few other bits and pieces).

Comment: ah! ok. I understand what you mean. But does that mean there's no way to do it?

Comment: Well you can draw you own frame (or use the Metal PL&F), but it is probably going to look wrong.